# Change background color after show the invisible columns in JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There are around 50 columns in my table, and I hide thirty columns initially when the table is created in order to speed up the loading process.
The user can set the columns visible later.

I use rowCallback to set up the background color of cells if the value of cell is greater than 0.

It only works well in the visible columns but not works for the invisible columns.

my code

```
var cols = [...]; // 50 columns 
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "data":data,
   "columns":cols,
   "columnDefs": [{"targets":[20,22,23,...49], "visible":false}],
   "rowCallback": function (row, data) {
     for (let i =0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] > 0) {
          $(row).find('td:eq(' + i + ')').css('background-color', '#B6E0FF');
        }
     }
   }
});
```

The result looks good.

When I set the invisible column to visible,

```
table.column(20).visible(true);
```

The 20th column is visible now, but the background color of cells are not changed.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In callback of Datatable you set the background color of td using jquery css, you can try to apply this after you change visibility.

something like:

```
 table.column(20).visible(true);
 //get the 20th col
 $('#example td:nth-child(20)').css('background-color', '#B6E0FF');
```